# Siri implementation app getting crash reason Terminating app due to uncaught exception

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit

> 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: _recordingTap == nil

getting crash at the code

```
1.  
guard let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode else {
        fatalError("Audio engine has no input node")
    }  
2.  
inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { (buffer, when) in
        self.recognitionRequest?.append(buffer)
}
```

When trying to reinitialize the siri it getting crashed

We have dictation of text also after dictation i want to capture text from speech . First time it is ok but second time it is getting crash at line 2

Speech dictation function given below

```
func getSpeech(asSpeach:String)
{
    print("===================")

    let audioSession  = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }


    /// <#Description#>
    let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: asSpeach)
    utterance.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate
    utterance.volume = 1.0
    utterance.pitchMultiplier = 1.0
    synthesizer.delegate=self
    synthesizer.speak(utterance)

    //        synthesizer.rSpeaking(at: .word)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you already have a tap installed on that bus and that you can't have another one.

When you call listen() initially you install the tap on the bus. 
Then you call stopListening() and you stop your recognition but you don't do anything about the tap. 
Then when you call listen() again you are trying to install the tap again - that produces the error.

You could add something to removeTapOnBus when you stopListening() - this should mean that you can add it back on again when you start listening again.